# How to alter an existing breadcrumb link programmatically?

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I am trying to alter the 'Home' Breadcrumb link using

`hook_system_breadcrumb_alter()`

The default Breadcrumb class allows you to add New links using the

`addLinks`

method.

However it does not allow one to edit the links. Is there a way to edit an existing link directly?

Answer (score 2):

Turns outs you can't edit the existing breadcrumbs. However you can fetch them using the getter function, modify them and then call the Breadcrumb builder class.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_system_breadcrumb_alter().
 */
function MODULE_system_breadcrumb_alter(Breadcrumb &$breadcrumb, RouteMatchInterface $route_match, array $context) {
  // Add new link
  $breadcrumb->addLink($link);
  // Saving the original links and caching
  $original_links = $breadcrumb->getLinks();
  $cacheability = CacheableMetadata::createFromObject($breadcrumb);
  // Remove the old value of the array.
  array_shift($original_links);
  $home_link = array_pop($original_links);
  array_unshift($original_links, $home_link);
  // Finally generating the new link.
  $breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
  $breadcrumb->setLinks($original_links);
  $breadcrumb->addCacheableDependency($cacheability);
}
```